# How to login with oAuth2 from a default popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension where I'd like to login to Twitch when the default icon is clicked. The examples, particularly https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/github-auth use the now-deprecated packaged app, whereas I'd like the actions to be available from default popup of a chrome extension. My `chrome.identity` is undefined (`"identity"` permission is in the manifest.json), and also redirecting to `https://<my-app-id>.chromiumapps.org/<anything>` does not work, says DNS entry is invalid. Has anyone solved this issue? To recap: I'd like to use oAuth2 flow from Chrome extension popup.

Comment: See [Open chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow as a tab (Chrome Extensions)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38152561)

Comment: Do you really mean [`chrome.identity`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity)? Or, is this an actual typo in your code?

Comment: fixed the typo.

Comment: _My chrome.identity is undefined ("identity" permission is in the manifest.json)_ Smells like trying to use it from a content script. Am I correct?

Comment: No, I don't have content scripts there.